# How to write a complex numpy array to excel using openpyxl

Tags: arrays, excel, python-3.x, numpy, openpyxl

I'm processing some complex number arrays in python. The program takes the data from excel using openpyxl, processes it and exports it as a numpy array of complex numbers, the problem is that excel doesn't supports the export format of numpy. 
it shows me this error:

```
ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
```

Converting the array into a full string doesn't work because I still need to access the array as rows and columns.
I already tried changing the array into a numpy string format and still get the same error output.

```
import openpyxl
import numpy

y=[[2.   -6.j]
  [1.   -3.j]
  [0.667-2.j]
  [1.   -3.j]
  [2.   -6.j]]


for fila in range (5,9):
   for val in range (0,4):
     hoja.cell(row=fila, column=6,value=y[val])


ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
```

Comment: You should include the full traceback but basically I think there is no way to serialise complex numbers in the OOXML format. You will need to decide for yourself how you want to do this before you add them to the worksheet.